# 403 when connecting to Exchange Online

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to use EWS on an Office 365 account however I get a return of (403 Forbidden)

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mv003237", "correctpw","domain");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("mv003237@domain.co.uk");
```

To login and view the Webservices file on outlook.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx I need to authenticate with mv003237@live.domain.co.uk

I have tried several combinations of this and still get the same error message.

Has anyone had a similar experience of connecting to an office 365 account before?

My WINDOWS login for this account does have a domain of RDG-HOME but I haven't seen a domain for login into OWA.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: did you try service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mv003237@domain.co.uk", "correctpw")?

Comment: Yeah I did - same 403 error :(

Comment: Change your last line to `service.AutodiscoverUrl("mv003237@domain.co.uk", redirect => true);` to follow the redirection response that Exchange Online sends.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you are awesome - please feel free to post as a question and I will mark it as an answer. Great work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already removed the domain name (as Matt suggested in his comment) the one thing that remains is to automatically follow redirects in the autodiscover process.

Change your last line to

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl("mv003237@domain.co.uk", redirect => true);
```

to follow the redirection response that Exchange Online sends.

So the complete sequence then becomes:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mv003237", "correctpw");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("mv003237@domain.co.uk", redirect => true);
```

Comment: I was hoping this is my solution but unfortunately it is not.  My issue is that I get a 403 only when I refresh the cache in my browser (we are loading our calendar in an iframe).  Sometimes on first load we get the error as well, but if it loads once correctly then the errors seem to stop. Any ideas why that may be? We're using the same code as noted above

Answer (score 2):

Cannot comment due to low reputation score and hence responding as an answer.

Are you able to login into OWA with "mv003237@domain.co.uk"? If yes, have you tried by hardcoding Url instead of using Autodiscover to understand if issue is with Autodiscover or EWS. Try following instead of autodiscover call:
service.Url = new Uri(@"https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx");

If above works fine, subscribe to RedirectionUrlValidationCallback with AutodiscoverService and see which redirected URL is throwing 403. Or enable verbose logging with Trace* properties present on service object.